# Sails routes node.js url issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, routes, sails.js

I have a simple controller:

```
var _ = require('underscore');
var request = require('request');


module.exports = {
    _config: { 
            actions: false,
             rest: false, 
             shortcuts: false 
        },

        index: function(req,res){
            console.log(req);
            var userName = req.body.userName;
            if(_.isEmpty(userName)){
                return res.view('apps/userSearch/userNotFound');
            } else {
              return res.view('apps/userSearch/userPage',
                    {
                        title: userName
                    }
           }
}
```

I have a simple form which accepts a text input of userName, which posts to /apps/UserSearchController, I am trying to setup routing so that my navigation points to localhost:1337/apps/userSearch.

When I navigate to apps/usersearch I will get my form, however when I type in a value and press submit, I will get redirected to localhost:1337/userSearch with the res.view on that url. however I would prefer the URL to still be apps/userSearch

my routes file is :

```
'/': {
    view: 'static/index'
  },
  '/apps/UserSearch': {
    view: 'apps/userSearch/userSearch'
  }
```

Does anyone know how to change the URL of the post request thankyou.